# Can someone explain this Python code structure?

Tags: python

I have a program with the following code:

```
    coros = [
        get_book(pair, session)
        for pair in PAIRS
    ]
```

How does this not give a syntax error? Or is it that if you do a for-loop in a list you have to put the function before the for-statement? I've never seen this but it's everywhere in the program.

Comment: > `Or is it that if you do a for-loop in a list you have to put the function before the for-statement?`

yup, if the function is not defined, you'll get a `NameError`

Answer (score 0):

It's a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) written in a non-standard way. The way it would usually be written is:

```
[get_book(pair, session) for pair in PAIRS]
```

It's equivalent to:

```
array = []
for pair in PAIRS:
    array.append(get_book(pair, session))
```